# Using redux combineReducers is creating a nested state

Tags: redux

When I use a redux reducer directly, I get the expected state:

```
import cheese from 'reducers/cheese.js';

const store = createStore( cheese );

<Provider store={ store } >
   ...
</Provider>
```

Results in:

```
cheese: "cheddar"
```

But when I use `combineReducer` I get a nested state

```
import cheese from 'reducers/cheese.js';
import crackers from 'reducers/crackers.js';

const reducer = combineReducers({ cheese, crackers });

const store = createStore( reducer );

<Provider store={ store } >
  ...
</Provider>
```

Results in:

```
cheese: { cheese: "cheddar" }
```

This is causing the shallow state comparison to validate, and my components don't update. (Edit: This assumption may be false)

**EDIT:**

My desired state looks like this (which is what it looks like when using a single reducer):

```
{
cheese: "cheddar",
crackers: "ritz"
}
```

**EDIT:**

My reducers look like this (same for both):

```
const initialState = {
  cheese: 'cheddar'
};

export default function reducer( state = initialState, action = {} ) {
  switch ( action.type ) {
    case 'newCheese':
      console.log(action.newCheese); // "cheddar"
      return {
        ...state,
        cheese: action.newCheese 
      };
  default:
    return state;
  }
}
```

Comment: That's the goal of `combineReducers`, so I'm not sure what your question is, since it's behaving as expected. Your `cheese` reducer seems to return an object instead of a value though.

Comment: How do you want the state to look after you combine cheese and crackers? Can you edit your question and provide your expected output?

Comment: I edited the question - thanks!

Comment: Your cheese reducer must then return just a scalar `"cheddar"`, not an object `{cheese: "cheddar"}`.

Answer (score 0):

`combineReducers` takes in an object - try:

```
const reducer = combineReducers({ cheese, crackers });
```

Comment: Thanks, you are correct, it does take an object. I made an error copying the code over from my live project, where I do pass an object, so unfortunately this is not the issue.